# Fluent NHibernate Conventions : OptimisticLock.Is(x => x.Version()) doesn't work

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I am having problems with using OptimisticLock as a Convention.
However, using OptimisticLock within Individual ClassMap's works fine. It throws Stale State Object Exceptions.

Each Class corresponding to a Table in the database has a property (which corresponds to a Column in the Table) of type DateTime which I am trying to use for Locking using OptimisticLock.Version().

It works only when I use it within every ClassMap, I don't want to write so many ClassMaps, I instead want to use Auto Mapping.

### It WORKS like this within the Class Map

`Version(x => x.UpdTs).Column("UPD_TS");
OptimisticLock.Version();`

### So, I started using Convention below, but it DOESN'T WORK.

```
OptimisticLock.IsAny(x => x.Version());
```

I tried setting the DynamicUpdate, etc. Nothing seems to work for me.
Please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did to get it work using a Convention :

```
/// <summary>
/// Class represents the Convention which defines which Property/Column serves as a part of the Optimistic Locking Mechanism.
/// </summary>
public class VersionConvention : IVersionConvention, IVersionConventionAcceptance
{
    public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IVersionInspector> criteria)
    {
        criteria.Expect(x => x.Name == "%COLUMN_NAME%");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method applies additional overrides to the <see cref="IVersionInstance"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="instance"><see cref="IVersionInstance"/></param>
    public void Apply(IVersionInstance instance)
    {            
        instance.Column("%COLUMN_NAME%");
    }
}
```

%COLUMN_NAME% above is the Property being used for Locking using Version.

Then specified that the Version should be used for Optimistic Locking, when creating a FluentConfiguration Object, like this

```
OptimisticLock.Is(x => x.Version();
```